# Accessibility on Angular 5+

Tags: angular, accessibility

When using [AXE](https://www.deque.com/axe/), I receive this error which I don't have in my code.

> ARIA attribute element ID does not exist on the page: aria-describedby="md-tooltip-1"

Here is my code:

```
<md-badge class="current-plan-type__icon--badge" direction="right"
            [mdPopover]="tootltipTemplate" delay="3000"
            popoverTrigger="MouseEnter">
            <i class="info"></i>
</md-badge>

<ng-template #tootltipTemplate>
     <div class="plan">
           <ul>
              <li>Something</li>
           </ul>
     </div>
</ng-template>
```

Here is what I see in Chrome Inspect:

```
<md-badge _ngcontent-sxh-c5="" 
class="current-plan-type__icon--badge" 
delay="3000" direction="right" 
popovertrigger="MouseEnter" 
ng-reflect-content="[object Object]" 
ng-reflect-direction="right" 
ng-reflect-delay="3000" 
ng-reflect-popover-trigger="MouseEnter" 
aria-describedby="md-tooltip-1">
```

Comment: At least your code is invalid, since `direction="right"` is not closed.

Comment: Care to share the generated HTML that you see in the Inspector, the `aria-describedby` is likely being added by your `mdPopover` but not generating the corresponding `<div>` with the correct ID. You can't rely on looking at your code when working with Angular etc. as it adds things via JavaScript automatically.

Comment: You need to inspect the actual DOM that is generated by `md-badge`

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I have edited my question. Please see what I see in inspector

Comment: I think you need to add the id attribute

Comment: @AjayReddy please see my edited Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something is malfunctioning with the module / plugin you are using or from a combination of modules / plugins (you haven't added some sort of accessibility module by any chance? The documentation you provided in a comment has no mention of `aria-describedby`, so my guess is something else is causing it to be created).

It is also strange that you are getting `md-tooltip` naming on popovers which is another reason why I think you have some conflicting modules / plugins

### To explain the error you are getting

> ARIA attribute element ID does not exist on the page: aria-describedby="md-tooltip-1"

This error is explaining that the element has an `aria-describedby` attribute that is saying that it's containing element (`md-badge`) is expecting to be named by an element with the ID 'md-tooltip-1'. The element with ID 'md-tooltip-1' is not being generated for some reason (or it could be generated and have `display: none` set - search in inspector -> elements for it just in case it is as simple as removing some CSS that is hiding the element)

This is shown as the last attribute you show in your edited question

```
ng-reflect-popover-trigger="MouseEnter" 
aria-describedby="md-tooltip-1"> // this is added automatically for you and is what is causing it to throw an error.
```

Assuming you have no errors in your console indicating why this element with the ID of "md-tooltip-1" was not created then you are only really left with a couple of options.

1. Try manually adding a  div with `id="md-tooltip-1"` and the description inside to your page for the popover. This will probably not be a good solution even if it works as I am guessing a second popover on the page will automatically get called "md-tooltip-2". It also creates new issues where you need to visually hide the div and make sure it has `aria-hidden="true"` or `display: none` unless the badge is being hovered. **not recommended due to complexity but an option**
2. Try adding an `aria-label="Identifying Text For The Popover"` to your `md-badge`, perhaps the `aria-labelledby` solution is attempting to provide some sort of fallback that expects a certain template design (i.e. it may be looking for a certain class or a heading to auto label it?). Having an `aria-label` may prevent this fallback mechanism from triggering. **best option if it works, also easiest to maintain**
3. Search all of your modules for `aria-describedby` and see if you can find the code generating it in the first place, it could be a bug that needs fixing in the core code that might be a simple fix. **not ideal as you may still have to deal with other issues mentioned in point 1 but could fix the problem**
4. You could manually create the element in HTML and wire it up using plain old vanilla JS, it is such a simple use case that using the core HTML from https://momentum.design/components/popover/code would mean this is really straight forward, but give you the flexibility you need to complete your accessibility work. **A great option if your use case is simple**

I am afraid without seeing the actual page code these are the best guesses for what is causing the issue and some possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you. So your first option worked. Option 3 & 4 is not applicable since I didn't have aria-describedby and I am using Angular 7, not Vanilla. Option 2, I tried it but didn't work

Comment: glad it worked, like I said just watch out for if you have more than one badge as this is a workaround rather than a fix (a perfectly acceptable workaround though! :-) )

Answer (score 0):

You need to import all necessary modules. I guess, it is the MdToolTipModule or something like that (depending on your version and used package) which you are missing.

Comment: I already have: https://momentum.design/components/popover/code

Comment: updated my answer. Sorry, I did not see that you are not using Angular Material but momentum design. But it still looks like the tooltip element is not found. Is it maybe just the typo in tooTltipTemplate or the missing closing ' " ' on "right?

Comment: so the direction is how the popover will open up, it will open up to the right. I have edited my question...I have used tootltipTemplate

Comment: so I copy/pasted wrong. But in the code, its correct. That is not the issue. you should know this, since the app wont even run and I will get syntax error.